# MySQL Calling One procedure in another and Inserting values into temporary table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two procedures say proc1 and proc2. I am calling one mysql procedure within another.

In proc1 I want to insert values from proc2 into proc1 temporary table.The proc2 returns two columns but i want to insert only one column into proc1 temporary table.

**The Output of Proc2 is as Below**

```
Hrs(Timestamp)    Status
09:30             IN,OUT,IN,OUT 
04:30             IN,OUT
07:30             IN,OUT,IN,OUT
04:25             IN,OUT
```

**Proc1 Code**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1()
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempWorkedHrs ;
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempWorkedHrs(WorkedHrs TIMESTAMP); 

   INSERT INTO TempWorkedHrs(WorkedHrs)
   CALL Proc2(); 

   SELECT SUM(WorkedHrs) INTO @TotalHrs
     FROM TempWorkedHrs;        
END //
```

The second column in proc2 is of no importance to me when I insert values into temporary table in proc1.

Q1. How to insert a particular column returned from procedure into temporary table? In my case first column from proc2.

Comment: I want to use already existing proc2 in proc1 and Insert values returned from proc2 into proc1 temporary table

Comment: can you show us, proc2 sample code? I don't understand what exactly are trying to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: This is not possible.

Long answer: This is not possible, but there are workarounds to achieve the same effect.

Option 1: Add a dummy column to your temporary table. Insert all columns from within `Proc2` into your temporary table. Then drop the dummy column. Dirty.

Option 2: Add a parameter to `Proc2`, a `BOOLEAN` is probably a good choice. Insert more or less columns depending on the parameter value. Less dirty.

Option 3: Do you really need `Proc2` be a procedure? In other words, does it really *modify* the data (or more generally, the environment) before *selecting* data? In other words, wouldn't a view be more suitable in this case?

[edit]

Thanks to James Holderness' pointer, I realized that you may not be aware that a stored procedure has no return value (there is no way around it). I took it for granted that by "`Proc2` returns data", you actually meant "`Proc2` writes into `TempWorkedHrs` some data that `Proc1` will read back". If you can, please avoid this approach (either option 1. or 2. is dirty anyways). You most probably need a view here.

Comment: Further to 0xCAFEBABE's comment, this is kind of weird a use case indeed, but hey, you asked it, so let's answer it. I wish I could answer X as well.

Comment: I thought it wasn't possible to do something like `INSERT INTO ... CALL` with mysql because stored procedures don't return anything. So options 1 and 2 wouldn't be of any help. It's not the number of columns that is the problem - there's just no way to get the results in any form. Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: @JamesHolderness Indeed, a procedure has no return value. We used a incorrect language shortcut, by "P2 returns data back to P1" we actually meant "P2 inserts some data in a temporary table (`TempWorkedHrs`) that P1 is able to read after P2 completion".

Comment: Aw... I see what you mean. I thought this fact was clear for the OP, I now realise s/he was actually hoping to be able to do something like this. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice but you could use triggers to execute your procedures.